# How can I get an model of foreign key along with the model. I tried using include

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to get the company details along with every employee. using node.js

I tried using "include".

`return Employee.db.findAll({where: {salary: amount}}, include: Company.db],
});`

Note: `empId` is the foreign key to `employee(id)`.

in db intialization:

```
EmployeeDb.belongsTo(CompanyDb, {foreignKey: 'companyId', targetKey: 'id'});
CompanyDb.hasMany(EmployeeDb, {foreignKey: 'companyId', sourceKey: 'id'});
```

I was expecting company object inside all the employee objects. But the company details are not retrieved

Comment: You are using the wrong syntax, try the following: `EmployeeDb.findAll({where: {salary: amount}, include: [{model: CompanyDb}]});` See examples in docs: https://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/associations.html#one-to-many-associations--hasmany-

Comment: Can you share more of the code where you are using the `include`? How are you instantiating `Employee` and `Company`?

Answer (score 0):

The below should work for you.

1. Changed `Employee.db` to `EmployeeDb` and `Company.db` to `CompanyDb`
2. `include` expects an Array.

```
return EmployeeDb.findAll(
  {
    where: {salary: amount},
    include: [CompanyDb]
  } 
);
```